# JMeter - jexl3 function can't declare local variables

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jexl

I'm using latest JMeter 4 and trying to use basic [jexl syntax](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) of declaring local variable in [jexl function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

> Local variables    Can be defined using the var keyword; their identifying rules are the same as contextual variables.
>   Basic declaration: var x;

So in JMeter I tried

```
${__jexl2(var x;)}
```

and succeeded, but using `${__jexl3(var x;)}` it throw an parser exception:

```
2018-04-25 14:18:16,451 ERROR o.a.j.f.Jexl3Function: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "var a;"

org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Parsing: @1:1 parsing error in 'var'
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlEngine.createExpression(JexlEngine.java:304) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Jexl3Function.execute(Jexl3Function.java:94) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getName(AbstractTestElement.java:165) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.sampler.DebugSampler.sample(DebugSampler.java:56) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Is it a JMeter issue or jexl3 issue, or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

In addition to failure to parse var, it can't parse `;`, here's a working example with jexl2 that failed with jexl3:

```
${__jexl3(abc=new("java.util.ArrayList"\, 1);)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62541) in JMeter Jexl3 implementation according to [jexl issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JEXL-263?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16544173#comment-16544173):

> JMeter using JexlExpression instead of JexlScript

Bug is fixed now and will be uploaded next version